# Зачем нужны аннотации в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, фреймворк

Начал разбираться с этим фреймворком и хотелось бы узнать вот что:

1. Почему мы подписываем некоторые элементы кода с помощью @SpringApplication например? Что будет если убрать эти аннотации. Что от этого поменяется? (Раньше пользовался этим только для того чтобы переопределять методы @Override, но там это было как-то понятно и особо не влияло).
2. Где именно хранятся базы данных, которые мы используем для разработки приложений? Ясное дело в памяти компьютера, но как приложение определяет откуда оно будет их брать и опять же, почему это работает?
3. Следствие из второго вопроса: если я например укажу в MySQL workbench подключение к серверу на котором стоит приложение(localhost:8080) и создам новую БД, то этого будет достаточно чтобы получить к ней доступ и использовать в дальнейшем в приложении?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85448/discussion-on-question-by-paper-kid-----spring).

Answer (score 3):

- Вы наверное имели ввиду аннотацию `@SpringBootApplication`, которая ставится над классом, а в `psvm` вы уже запускаете `SpringApplication.run(Application.class)`. Например, эта аннотация нужна, чтобы рефлексийно определить класс, в котором есть точка доступа в приложение. Например аннотации `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository` и `@Controller` нужны для того, чтобы определить классы, объекты которых будут beans.
- Базы данных могут храниться на том же сервере, где и хранится приложение, а так же и на удаленном, отдельном сервере. Подключение зависит от того, какой вы способ выбрали(`JDBC`, `Spring JDBC`, `Hibernate`, `Spring Data JPA`). Например, в приложении, где используется `SpringBoot` вам можно настроить всё в `application.properties` и все будет работать.
- Да, достаточно создать базу данных и указать правильный ***url*** к ней в приложении, и этого будет достаточно. Но для правильного взаимодействия вам нужно будет настроить еще поддержку версионности базы данных, например `flyway`.